# Concatenate strings in jq

Tags: jq

My input looks like:

```
{
    "font1": {
        "charInfo": [
            {
                "char": "a",
                "other_stuff": 12
            },
            {
                "char": "b",
                "other_stuff": 63
            }
        ]
    },
    "font2": {
        "charInfo": [
            {
                "char": "s",
                "other_stuff": 1
            },
            {
                "char": "x",
                "other_stuff": 4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

and I'd like to aggregate (ideally concatenate) the "char"-s per font:

```
{
    "font1": "ab",
    "font2": "sx"
}
```

How can achieve this using jq?

This is what I have so far:

```
jq '. | keys[] as $font | {font: $font} + .[$font] | {font:.font, chars:[.charInfo[].char]|join("")}'
enter code here
```

Which brings it to:

```
{
  "font": "font1",
  "chars": "ab"
}
{
  "font": "font2",
  "chars": "sx"
}
```

but I can't find how I turn the "font" to a key of a map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add` to concatenate, and `|=` to update:

```bash
jq '.[] |= ([.charInfo[].char] | add)'
```

```json
{
  "font1": "ab",
  "font2": "sx"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/nlwazy_Fwvu)

Answer (score 2):

Not efficient, but maybe a bit clearer leveraging `map_values` and `join`:

```
map_values(.charInfo|map(.char)|join(""))
```